# Determining whether an input is a file or directory

Tags: perl, file, compare, subdirectory

I am currently writing a program that will eventually compare the files in two directories and display the functions that have changed in each file. However, I have run into a problem when checking to see if what is in the directory is a file or is a sub-directory.

Right now, when I check to see if it is simply a directory with the `-d` check, it doesn't catch any of the sub-directories. I have posted parts of my code below.

```
opendir newDir, $newDir;
my @allNewFiles = grep { $_ ne '.' and $_ ne '..'} readdir newDir;
closedir newDir;

opendir oldDir, $oldDir;
my @allOldFiles = grep { $_ ne '.' and $_ ne '..'} readdir oldDir;
closedir oldDir;


foreach (@allNewFiles) {
    if(-d $_) {
        print "$_ is not a file and therefore is not able to be compared\n\n";
    } elsif((File::Compare::compare("$newDir/$_", "$oldDir/$_") == 1)) {
        print "$_ in new directory $newDirName differs from old directory $oldDirName\n\n";
        print OUTPUTFILE "File: $_ has been update. Please check marked functions for differences\n";
        print OUTPUTFILE "\n\n";
        print OUTPUTFILE "+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=\n\n";
    } elsif((File::Compare::compare("$newDir/$_", "$oldDir/$_") < 0)) {
        print "$_ found in new directory $newDirName but not in old directory $oldDirName\n";
        print "Entire file not printed to output file but instead only file name\n";
        print OUTPUTFILE "File: $_ is a new file!\n\n";
        print OUTPUTFILE "+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=\n\n";
    }
 }

foreach (@allOldFiles) {
    if((File::Compare::compare("$newDir/$_", "$oldDir/$_") < 0)) {
        print "$_ found in old directory $oldDirName but not in new directory $newDirName\n\n";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Two things: 1. Bareword handles are bad (of course, you've been told this because you `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, *right*?), and 2. why not just do `grep{-f $_}` on `readdir` of the directory handle?

Comment: I do use use stricts; and use warnings; And when I tried to just use grep{-f $_} it wouldn't read any files except perl files.

Comment: Then start. Unless you're doing a throw-away one-liner, you should `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in every single bit of Perl code that you write.

Comment: Why are you doing all the work yourself instead of running `diff -rq $oldDir $newDir`?

Comment: I don't know how to use diff in perl and I can't find any documentation on how to do so online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [perldoc -f readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) states:

> If you're planning to filetest the return values out of a readdir,
>   you'd better prepend the directory in question. Otherwise, because we
>   didn't chdir there, it would have been testing the wrong file.

```
if(-d "$newDir/$_") {
```

Answer (score 3):

use [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~kwilliams/Path-Class-0.25/)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Class;


my @allNewFiles = grep { !$_->is_dir } dir("/newDir")->children;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive call to get the list of files first and then operate on them.

```
my $filesA = {};
my $filesB = {};

# you are passing in a ref to filesA or B so no return is needed.
sub getFiles {
  my ($dir, $fileList) = @_;

  foreach my $file (glob("*")) {
    if(-d $file) {
      getFiles($dir . "/" . $file, $fileList); # full relative path saved
    } else {
      $fileList{$dir . "/" . $file}++;         # only files are put into list
    }
  }
}

# get the files list
my $filesA = getFiles($dirA);
my $filesB = getFiles($dirB);

# check them by using the keys from the 2 lists created.
```